# How can I save an RDD into HDFS and later read it back?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd, bigdata

I have an RDD whose elements are of type (Long, String). For some reason, I want to save the whole RDD into the HDFS, and later also read that RDD back in a Spark program. Is it possible to do that? And if so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible.

In RDD you have `saveAsObjectFile` and `saveAsTextFile` functions. Tuples are stored as `(value1, value2)`, so you can later parse it.

Reading can be done with `textFile` function from SparkContext and then `.map` to eliminate `()`

So:
Version 1:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile ("hdfs:///test1/");
// later, in other program
val newRdds = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs:///test1/part-*").map (x => {
    // here remove () and parse long / strings
})
```

Version 2:

```
rdd.saveAsObjectFile ("hdfs:///test1/");
// later, in other program - watch, you have tuples out of the box :)
val newRdds = sparkContext.sc.sequenceFile("hdfs:///test1/part-*", classOf[Long], classOf[String])
```

Comment: Vow, that is a neat solution :). But how do we read using textFile, since saveAsText would make many different files.

Comment: @pythonic See my update - you can read range of file. Each part of RDD is saved in file `part-XYZŹŻ`, so we can read just each file of such name

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to use DataFrame if your RDD is in tabular format. a data frame is a table, or two-dimensional array-like structure, in which each column contains measurements on one variable, and each row contains one case.
a DataFrame has additional metadata due to its tabular format, which allows Spark to run certain optimizations on the finalized query.
where a RDD is a Resilient Distributed Dataset that is more of a blackbox or core abstraction of data that cannot be optimized.
However, you can go from a DataFrame to an RDD and vice-versa, and you can go from an RDD to a DataFrame (if the RDD is in a tabular format) via toDF method.

The following is the example to create/store a DataFrame in CSV and Parquet format in HDFS,

```
val conf = {
   new SparkConf()
     .setAppName("Spark-HDFS-Read-Write")
 }

 val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

 val hdfs = "hdfs:///"
 val df = Seq((1, "Name1")).toDF("id", "name")

 //  Writing file in CSV format
 df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite").save(hdfs + "user/hdfs/employee/details.csv")

 // Writing file in PARQUET format
 df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(hdfs + "user/hdfs/employee/details")

 //  Reading CSV files from HDFS
 val dfIncsv = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load(hdfs + "user/hdfs/employee/details.csv")

 // Reading PQRQUET files from HDFS
 val dfInParquet = sqlContext.read.parquet(hdfs + "user/hdfs/employee/details")
```